# -bash: export: `=': not a valid identifier

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, export

Every time I open my terminal I get the error below:

```
Last login: Sun Aug  4 17:23:05 on ttys000
-bash: export: `=': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `=': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin': not a valid identifier
```

And here is my `export` output:

```
Calvin:~ sunkehappy$ export
declare -x Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render="/tmp/launch-4lEZNa/Render"
declare -x Apple_Ubiquity_Message="/tmp/launch-ukGAv5/Apple_Ubiquity_Message"
declare -x COMMAND_MODE="unix2003"
declare -x HOME="/Users/sunkehappy"
declare -x LANG="zh_CN.UTF-8"
declare -x LOGNAME="sunkehappy"
declare -x OLDPWD
declare -x PATH="/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin"
declare -x PWD="/Users/sunkehappy"
declare -x SECURITYSESSIONID="186a4"
declare -x SHELL="/bin/bash"
declare -x SHLVL="1"
declare -x SSH_AUTH_SOCK="/tmp/launch-YAEryC/Listeners"
declare -x TERM="xterm-256color"
declare -x TERM_PROGRAM="Apple_Terminal"
declare -x TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION="309"
declare -x TERM_SESSION_ID="B134A404-D87F-4BB9-8A08-55F8CE923339"
declare -x TMPDIR="/var/folders/kt/pfw99tps22gg2019vz8k1zcm0000gn/T/"
declare -x USER="sunkehappy"
declare -x __CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING="0x1F5:25:52"
```

Answer (score 212, accepted):

You cannot put spaces around the `=` sign when you do:

```
export foo=bar
```

Remove the spaces you have and you should be good to go.

If you type:

```
export foo = bar
```

the shell will interpret that as a request to export three names: `foo`, `=` and `bar`. `=` isn't a valid variable name, so the command fails. The variable name, equals sign and it's value must not be separated by spaces for them to be processed as a simultaneous assignment and export.

Comment: How can I fix it? I mean those error occur when I open the terminal. I guess this is a error in the configuration file but I don't know where it is.

Comment: I know it. I have edited my ./bash_profile before. Now I fix by editing it again. Thanks.

Comment: I wanted to add Google Chrome to my Path, and the path contains a white space, e.g. `/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS` And I was getting this error. 
To fix it, I had to enclose the path in `" "`

Answer (score 12):

I faced the same error and did some research to only see that there could be different scenarios to this error. Let me share my findings.

**Scenario 1: There cannot be spaces beside the `=` (equals) sign**

```
$ export TEMP_ENV = example-value
-bash: export: `=': not a valid identifier
// this is the answer to the question

$ export TEMP_ENV =example-value
-bash: export: `=example-value': not a valid identifier

$ export TEMP_ENV= example-value
-bash: export: `example-value': not a valid identifier
```

**Scenario 2: Object value assignment should not have spaces besides quotes**

```
$ export TEMP_ENV={ "key" : "json example" } 
-bash: export: `:': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `json example': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `}': not a valid identifier
```

**Scenario 3: List value assignment should not have spaces between values**

```
$ export TEMP_ENV=[1,2 ,3 ]
-bash: export: `,3': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `]': not a valid identifier
```

I'm sharing these, because I was stuck for a couple of hours trying to figure out a workaround. Hopefully, it will help someone in need.

Comment: No space between the = (equals) sign was the issue that I was grappling with. I appreciate you hinting out at checking that first before anything else.

Answer (score 10):

I was using dash '-' instead of underscore '_' in the variable name.

```
# fails 
$ export MY-NAME="abc"

# success
$ export MY_NAME="abc"
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all go to the /home directorty then open invisible shell script with some text editor, `~/.bash_profile (macOS) or ~/.bashrc (linux)` go to the bottom, you would see something like this,

> export LD_LIBRARY_PATH = /usr/local/lib

change this like that( remove spaces around the `=` ),

> export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib

it should be useful.

Comment: is there a any info about bashrc in the answer. Are we going to changed /home/user export command results or something else ? Did you see any info about this.

Answer (score 2):

Try to surround the path with quotes, and remove the spaces

```
export PYTHONPATH="/home/user/my_project":$PYTHONPATH
```

And don't forget to preserve previous content suffixing by **:$PYTHONPATH** (which is the value of the variable)

Execute the following command to check everything is configured correctly:

```
echo $PYTHONPATH
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem when I put a dollar sign before variable name, like that:

```
$VARIABLE_NAME=value
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and figured it out from your comments, but thought I would add the reason I caused the error to occur (for other beginners).

I had opened and edited .bash_profile using the open command in Terminal, which opened it in Text Editor. I typed in an addition to .bash_profile and it used improper quote characters. I opened .bash_profile in Atom and fixed up the error. I also associated the file with Atom for future editing.

Answer (score 0):

I recently tried executing a bash script containing a few lines:

```
export var1=xxx
unset var2
```

and I was getting unexpected lines

```
': not a valid identifierS
```

because the script had been created on Windows and copied to Linux and contained wrong EOL characters. Switching to the correct encoding fixed the issue. So wrong EOL characters could also generate a similar error.