# Bash :vim: command not found

Tags: node.js

I keep getting

> -bash: export:
> `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/nodejs/bin':
> not a valid identifier in my terminal

while trying to install node.js on mac I don't know what I did wrong. I also can not run any command on my terminal I keep getting commands not found

Comment: Look like you have some syntax problem in your exported vars ,  check this old post looks similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18042369/bash-export-not-a-valid-identifier

Comment: Still have the same error 
Last login: Tue Oct 11 14:09:51 on ttys000
-bash: export: `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/nodejs/bin': not a valid identifier
Akeems-MacBook-Air:~ mac$

Comment: My guess is that your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` contains something like `export $PATH=...` instead of the correct code, `export PATH=...`.

Comment: seems there is backticks in  ```export: `/usr/```, it should be single quote.